# Slim PHP custom http response pages

Tags: php, httpresponse, http-status-code-403, slim

Ok I have read the docs on *Slim PHP* and read quite a few tutorials, and have an application nicely under way. However I am trying to get to grips with things such as customizing the HTTP response codes. I have managed to get the following :

```
$app->notfound('template.file', array(
    'data' => 'passed'
));
```

This seems to work nicely (as it should as it *is* a Method directly within Slim), however not I am trying to control things such as the `403` response. I have controlled the not permitted using Apache as I usually would do, however I am wondering if there is a way with Slim that I can serve a custom **Not Permitted** page? Or because I have blocked it at the Apache level, will Slim not even notice?

I did read that I can manually **halt** certain routes? Is this the way I should do it? For example, I don't want people to access my JS directory so :

```
$app->group('/js', function () use($app) {
    $app->get('/', functin () use($app) {
        $app->halt(403, "You shall not pass!");
    });
});
```

My reason for **grouping** this would be because I want access to my actual scripts, just not directory browsing.

Has anybody come across this before? What would you suggest? Or am I totally over thinking something simple....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply redirect user to another route where you print your custom template. Example:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->group('/js', function () use($app) {
    $app->get('/', function () use($app) {
        $app->flash('httpStatusCode', '403');
        $app->redirectTo('NotAuthorized');
    });
});

$app->get('/notAuthorized', function () use($app) {
    echo 'You\'re here because you\'re Balrog!';
    echo 'Http Status Code: ' . $_SESSION['slim.flash']['httpStatusCode'];
})->name('NotAuthorized');

$app->run();
```

Comment: I didn't think of that! Is there a way I can get the http status code and feed it into the page?

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb, how do I get Flash messages to actually work? I tried this (I installed the Slim-extra package through composer), I tried to start off the Session class within my application, but when I said `$app->flash('message', 'something')` it didn't work and complained about my usage of it?

Comment: What version of Slim are you using?

Comment: As far as I am aware the latest - `"require":{
  "php":">=5.3.0",
  "slim/slim": "~2.5",
  "slim/views": "~0.1"
 }`

Comment: Try to see my updated answer. It works fine on my local machine.

Comment: If that will issue an external redirect (don’t know details about Slim), then that would be a really bad idea.